# Unix timestamp function not returning expected timestamp, wrong timezone?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, unix

I'm using a custom function to take the current date and subtract days on it then return a timestamp in unix format. All the conversions are working fine except the expected output is not correct. I thought by setting

> DateTime(DateTime.UtcNow.Year, DateTime.UtcNow.Month, DateTime.UtcNow.Day, 0, 0, 0)

to `0,0,0` that it would give me that day on midnight but it's giving me 5am (GMT).

My custom function:

```
public static int getUnixTimestamp(int days) {
    // Date to convert
    DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(DateTime.UtcNow.Year, DateTime.UtcNow.Month, DateTime.UtcNow.Day, 0, 0, 0).AddDays(-days);

    return (int)(TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(dateTime) -
           new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, System.DateTimeKind.Utc)).TotalSeconds;
}
```

Any ideas or feedback on what could be causing this would be great, thanks!

Comment: Isn't Unix timestamps _seconds_ since epoch, not days?

Comment: @silkfire That shouldn't matter I wouldn't think, I'm converting a DateTime to a unix timestamp.

Comment: Sorry, missed that part. Have you tried the `DateTimeOffset.ToUnixTimeSeconds` method available in .NET v4.6?

Comment: @silkfire Sadly my project is on .net 2 and I don't have the option to update to 4+. That would be really nice to have though.

Comment: What kind of company uses such an old framework ;)

Comment: Software that was built on that older language and is too large to be updated easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calling the `DateTime` constructor *without* specifying a `Kind`, then you're calling `ConvertTimeToUtc`. That's going to *assume* that `dateTime` is actually local, and convert it to UTC. Given that you're already constructing it with UTC values, you don't need to convert it.

You have a separate problem which is calling `DateTime.UtcNow` several times - the date could change between those calls. It's better to use `DateTime.UtcNow.Date` to get the "today-in-UTC date".

Here's better code:

```
private static readonly DateTime UnixEpoch =
    new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, System.DateTimeKind.Utc);

// TODO: Give this a clearer name
public static int GetUnixTimestamp(int days)
    => (int) ((DateTime.UtcNow.Date.AddDays(-days) - UnixEpoch).TotalSeconds);
```

Importantly, the `Kind` of `DateTime.UtcNow.Date.AddDays(-days)` will still be `DateTimeKind.Utc`.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation! Will accept when available.